# Kafka block.on.buffer.full default value

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I was going over the kafka(0.9.0.1) producer configuration, and the property `block.on.buffer.full` in the documentation says:

> When our memory buffer is exhausted we must either stop accepting new
>   records (block) or throw errors.  **By default this setting is true**  and
>   we block, however in some scenarios blocking is not desirable and it
>   is better to immediately give an error. Setting this to false will
>   accomplish that: the producer will throw a BufferExhaustedException if
>   a recrord is sent and the buffer space is full.

So theoretically it should be true, but in that same documentation (http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html) the table has a column called "default" that points out that the default value is actually false.

Which one is correct?

Comment: I think that it's a bug in the documentation. For example, here it's set to false https://apache.googlesource.com/kafka/+/0.8.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleProducer.scala#58

Comment: Its clear that this is a bug in the configuration, but what I am trying to figure it out is the actual default value.

Comment: you can see in the source code ... https://apache.googlesource.com/kafka/+/0.9.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerConfig.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F it's false

Comment: yes, Thanks Markon I found it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value is false.

Here is the producer default [configuration](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/d5b43b19bb06e9cdc606312c8bcf87ed267daf44/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerConfig.java#L232) for the latest release.

Comment: You should approve your answer - it's possible to do so.

Comment: You are right, the code and javadoc are also wrong:

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the code and javadoc are also wrong, see ProducerConfig class:

The javadoc says, it defaults to true.

```
 @Deprecated
    public static final String BLOCK_ON_BUFFER_FULL_CONFIG = "block.on.buffer.full";
    private static final String BLOCK_ON_BUFFER_FULL_DOC = "When our memory buffer is exhausted we must either stop accepting new records (block) or throw errors. **By default this setting is true** and we block, however in some scenarios blocking is not desirable and it is better to immediately give an error. Setting this to <code>false</code> will accomplish that: the producer will throw a BufferExhaustedException if a recrord is sent and the buffer space is full.";
```

However, the code sets it to false :).

```
 .define(BLOCK_ON_BUFFER_FULL_CONFIG, Type.BOOLEAN, **false,** Importance.LOW, BLOCK_ON_BUFFER_FULL_DOC)
```

Anyways, it is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: If `block.on.buffer.full` is not set, what exactly happens when the buffer is full? What happens with `block.ms` when `block.on.buffer.full` is left `false`?

Comment: Found the answer at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2791 in the form of an old warning: *`block.on.buffer.full` config is deprecated and will be removed soon. Please use `max.block.ms`*